# Checking if this transformation $L: R^3 \to P_4$ exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been given three vectors: $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and asked if it is possible for there to be a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow P_4$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\end{bmatrix}\mapsto x^2$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\mapsto x^2-1$, and $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 1$.

My professor goes about saying that this must be true since the vectors are linearly independent, but I'm having trouble figuring out why linear independence means this transformation must be possible. Can anyone help clarify why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear independence of 3 vectors, say $u_1,u_2,u_3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ means that they form a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e. any vector $v$ can be represented as a linear combination of those three: $v=a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3u_3$. This means, in turn, that any choice of values for $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ can be extended linearly to any vector $v \in \mathbb R^3$, thus defining the linear transformation.

Comment: So are you saying that, since the three vectors can make any vector in $R^3$, and $R^3$ can be mapped to $P_4$, then there must be some transformation that is able to combine the vectors in such a way as to get the results stated?

Comment: Not sure I'd put it this way, but to put it more formally: if you define values of $L$ for $u_1,u_2,u_3$ as  $w_1,w_2,w_3$ respectively  (where $w_k \in P_4$) then you can extent $L$ to all of $R^3$ : $L(v) = L(a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3 u_3) = a_1 L(u_1) + a_2 L(U_2) + a_3 L(u_3) = a_1w_1 + a_2w_2 + a_3w_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=[1,2,3]^T,$ $x_2=[0,1,1]^T,$ $x_3=[1,1,1]^T.$ $1,x,x^2$ is linear independent in $P_4.$ So let $y_1=x^2=[0,0,1]^T,$ $y_2=x^2-1=[-1,0,1]^T,$ $y_3=1=[1,0,0]^T.$

You want to find a linear transformation $A,$ such that $Ax_i=y_i,$ $i=1,2,3.$ Write it into $$A[x_1,x_2,x_3]=[y_1,y_2,y_3]\Rightarrow AX=Y$$
Here $X=[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is invertible since $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is linear independent. So $A=YX^{-1}$ is a unique solution.

Comment: $x^2=[0,0,1]^T$ is a terrible abuse of notation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought it was understandable. What's your advise?